# WPF / Xaml: tag not available. I just don't get it. Who can explain the compiler message?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I am new to WPF / Xaml. I tried to run a demo program to test WPF with NHibernate. I used the [VmWrapperDemo](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfNhibernateToolkit.aspx?display=Print) but i cant get it compiled!

```
<Window x:Class="VmWrapperDemo.View.WindowMain"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:VmWrapperDemo.ViewModel;assembly=VmWrapperDemo"
    Title="VM Collection Demo" Height="325" Width="500" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- Value Converters -->
        <vm:ContactConverter x:Key="ContactConverter" /> 
        <vm:AmountConverter x:Key="AmountConverter" />
        <vm:DateConverter x:Key="DateConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

It is the

```
 xmlns:vm ...
```

definition which i dont understand and gives me headaches. What does it mean i why do i get the following compiler error:
"The tag ContactConverter is not available"

I am lost! Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

change `assembly=VmWrapperDemo` to `assembly=VmWrapperDemo.ViewModel`

Assembly name in the link you gave is `VmWrapperDemo.ViewModel` not `VmWrapperDemo`

Comment: Strange... when I do `assembly=VmWrapperDemo"` I get exact same error as you do and when I write complete name I get no error

Comment: Now i changed all Namespace and Using directives to "VmWrapperDemo". Name of assembly is "VmWrapperDemo" too. Result is the same... I just don't understand it...

Comment: Could there anything wrong with my project or build settings?

Comment: No I don't think so. I would suggest keep the names as they are in original project and then try my suggestion. May be it would be a good idea to get clean copy from link you mentioned

Comment: assembly can be omitted if the clr-namespace referenced is being defined within the same assembly as the application code that is referencing the custom classes. Or, an equivalent syntax for this case is to specify assembly=, with no string token following the equals sign.

--> and this is my solution! Without the assembly=VmWrapperDemo it works perfectly. Many thanks Haris for your help!